# square to cross? best way?/just an annoyance

Tags: edges, extrude

Something I find annoying or maybe I'm just missing something? Quickest way to make a square into a cross? My current way is to extrude two opposite edges then scale them out. Repeat the process for the other two. Is there a quicker way?
[image]

Comment: hello maybe begin with a cube, select all the vertical faces and Alt E > Extrude Individual Faces?

Comment: Valid... thx. don't like starting with a cube and delete to get a plain but yeah it works. :)

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure there's any other solution  :(

Comment: the "solution" is an extrude edge normal that works like extrude face normal... but that's not in there yet. i have hope!

Answer (score 4):

Begin with a cube, select all the vertical faces and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Individual Faces*, then activate the *Auto Merge* option and scale on Z (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Auto Merge... yuck. getting to complex. :))

Comment: or select all and press M > Merge by Distance   ;)

Answer (score 3):

Create a grid, 3 x 3, go in edit mode, face select, select 4 faces, x

[image]

---

UPDATE: i don't wanna disappoint moonboots:

[image]

or

[image]

or (because mesh booleans are evil and slow):

[image]

Comment: Man, were you not supposed to propose the GEONODE solution?????!!??? I'm so disappointed   O_o

Comment: nice approach. thanks.

Comment: @moonboots: i updated my answer

Comment: @Chris  mmmmh i feel much better

Comment: You should split these into separate answers.